# Having trouble allocating a structure array

Tags: c

My project requires me to allocate memory dynamically. What am I doing wrong?

```
/*Setting up my Struture*/
struct album_ {
  int num_tracks;
  struct tracks_ tracks;
  int playlist_hits[];
};
typedef struct album_ album;

/*Try to allocate memory for structure*/

fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_album);

  album *all_albums_p = (album *)malloc(sizeof(album)*number_of_album);

  for(i=0;i < number_of_album; i++){
    all_albums_p[i].num_tracks = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    all_albums_p[i].num_tracks = i+1;
    printf("%d\n",all_albums_p[i].num_tracks);
  }

Error Message
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Also if I wanted to return this array is it correct to `return all_albums_p`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
all_albums_p[i].num_tracks = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
all_albums_p[i].playlist_hits = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Since you are allocating an array of `album`, you need to replace the *flexible array* member with a pointer: `playlist_hits` should be changed to `int*`.

Comment: if I change that I get `functions.c:19:5: error: invalid use of flexible array member`
`functions.c:20:5: error: invalid use of flexible array member`

Comment: @LearningC Please see my last edit. You wouldn't be able to use structs with flexible arrays in an array unless all flexible arrays are of the same size (and it does not look like they are of the same size in your example).

Comment: Thanks I got it now. Fixed that issue. Another issues is I'm trying to `return all_albums_p;` but it also giving me this error `warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: @LearningC Did you forget to provide the return type of your function?

Answer (score 0):

The complaining line is

```
all_albums_p[i].num_tracks = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

you assign a pointer to an int to it. That will cause a memory leak.
I have no idea what you intend with that

This line is also strange

```
all_albums_p[i].num_tracks = i+1;
```

you have n album and you say the number of tracks will be depend on the index of the album. This is very unlikely.

the first album has 1 track.

The thousandth album has 1000 tracks.

does not sound very rational

Comment: I was just trying to test it out. I will read in a number and it will tell me the number of albums. Then I'll have to read in another number that will tell me the number of tracks.